# New Bar with Activity Link

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, recent-activity, top-bar

I frequently use the [Activity Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220577/bala?tab=activity&sort=all) in the header before, now there is no option in the new bar, that link help me to check my close votes activity. Is it possible to have the option for **Activity Link** like before when mouse over on the profile picture.

Otherwise I need to navigate to [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220577/bala) and then need to click the activity link.